# Popover content - Button is not being displayed inside the popover (JQuery / Javascript / HTML / Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

So I'm using FullCalendar (v5), and I have managed to implement popovers (using bootstrap) for events on the timeline. I'm wanting to include a button to remove an event, however the button is not appearing inside of the popover.
This is really strange, as the html button tags are being completely ignored (having put the button element in between two other elements to check this). Code can be seen below:

```
 eventDidMount: function (info) {
                var content = 'Duration: ' + moment(info.event.startStr).format('hh:mma') + ' - ' + moment(info.event.endStr).format('hh:mma')                  
                $(info.el).popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: info.event.title + '<button type="button" id="remove-btn">Remove</button>' + '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="popover">&times;</a>',
                    placement: 'top',
                    trigger: 'click',
                    content:content,                                        
                    container: 'body'
                });
                $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function () {
                    $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
                });
            },
```

The result of this popover creation can be seen here:
[Popover Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2PKx.png)

The button should be displayed in between the title the close button. It's worth noting that I have tried a couple of different ways to accomplish this, such as creating hidden HTML elements and getting the html from a callback function, or trying to put the button element inside of the content string instead of title. Neither of these work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVak6/8/) demonstrates exactly what I'm trying to achieve (The button is inside the content string, however I have tried exactly this code with my solution and it does not work)

Comment: What are you using to implement the popovers? Is it bootstrap maybe? The issue seems to be to do with how they handle HTML elements in the title. maybe check the documentation for the popover, and re-tag your question if you're still stuck. I can't see any obvious relationship to fullCalendar here - the popovers are not part of that library. I expect you would have a similar issue if you used the popover outside of any calendar elements or code

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I am using bootstrap to achieve this. I have checked the documentation, and I have also seen solutions that create popovers in this way, with buttons that appear, although they are in the content string, it seems to make no difference, as it does not appear using either method. The only difference betwen my implementation and theirs, is that I am attempting to attach popevers to events inside of FullCalender and not a standard  html element.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRjyyPY . The button is ok.

Comment: Have tried your code, still no success. So far, the only way I have been able to get any type of button inside the popover is by directly editing the HTML in the Chrome Inspector... This is madening, lol

Comment: You'll need to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then, before we can help you. It's impossible to know what is wrong when the code you have provided doesn't demonstrate the problem. Maybe you can fork my CodePen and edit it, until it shows your problem, that might be an easy way to create a demo.

Comment: Hey ADyson,  I have tried my best to re-create a stripped down version of what I'm using atm. Note that I am using the Resource Timeline, which is a premium feature, I am having trouble getting it to display because of this I think. you can see the code here. https://codepen.io/christakus/pen/rNMpqrp (Sorry this is my first time using CodePen)

Comment: This code however, does reproduce the problem that I'm having. https://codepen.io/christakus/pen/rNMpqrp

Comment: You just needed to use the fullcalendar scheduler JS file, instead of the basic fullCalendar one. Here's an updated version of your codePen which does that, and has the code formatted sensible (there's a button for automated formatting in the drop-down menu on the right hand side of the JS pane): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gOwoEKm . Anyway, it doesn't seem to reproduce your problem - you've got the button in the content area and it shows up fine. If we alter it to put a button into the title, it also shows up fine: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxEpBaK. So I still don't know your issue.

Comment: I never managed to solve the issue as to why the button was not appearing however, after adding a specialized bootstrap plugin (bootstrap-confirmation) I was able to attach one of their confirmation popovers to the events, and it works like a charm. Thank you so much for all your help. I know it was never resolved, but I greatly appreciate your assistance nonetheless. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use `sanitize: false`

```
$(info.el).popover({
  html: true,
  title: info.event.title + '<button type="button" id="remove-btn">Remove</button>' + '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="popover">&times;</a>',
  placement: 'top',
  sanitize: false,
  trigger: 'click',
  content:content,                                        
  container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.